# CSS Transition is not working in reverse direction for me even after correct transition rules

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

The CSS Transition is working fine, but when I move my cursor away then it does into transition back instead it abruptly back to the original style.

Here is my code:

```css
.form-component button {
  align-self: end;
  margin-left: 35px;
  position: relative;
  background-color: black;
  height: 120px;
  width: 140px;
  border: 1px solid #db6345;
  border-radius: 50%;
  color: #b5ab9a;
  font-size: 20px;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: color 0.35s ease, border-width 0.9s ease;
}

.form-component .circle-layer {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  background: #db6345;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transition: height 0.9s ease, width 0.9s ease;
  z-index: -1;
}

.form-component button:hover .circle-layer {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.form-component button:hover {
  color: black;
  border-width: 0px;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div name="project-details-validator" class="form-component">
  <textarea placeholder="Project details and clarifications " rows="8"></textarea>

  <button hover="true" id="send-button">
        <div class="circle-layer" id="send-button-circle-layer" hover="true"></div>
        SEND
    </button>
</div>
```

I tried adding transition ease for all the properties but even that did not work.

Comment: The z-index rule on `.form-component .circle-layer` is what's causing the problem; the transition is happening, it's just not visible because it's "behind" the dark circle.

Comment: Thanks a lot Daniel! This is indeed what is causing the problem.